# CSS3 Transition Effect Issue

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am currently trying to learn CSS3 techniques to implement on my website. I found this code online for sliding image boxes (http://www.pixelforlife.com/html-css3-sliding-image-boxes/). When you hover over the boxes, its supposed to move upwards revealing the text hidden behind it. The problem is when I run it on chrome, firefox or IE the smooth transition effect doesn't work. I tried to change the webkit values and stuff but still couldn't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> www.PixelForLife.com - Sliding Block </title>

<style type="text/css">
body { font: 13px sans-serif; }

#montage-wrap   { width: 820px; height: 200px; }
.montage-block  { width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; display: block; overflow: hidden; position: relative; 
        margin: 0 4px 0 0; background: white; border: 1px solid #666;}
.montage-block:last-child    { margin: 0; } /* removes margin on last block */

#block1 { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; display: block;
        background: url("pixelforlife_thumb.png") no-repeat; 

        -webkit-transition: top .3s ease-in-out; }

.montage-block:hover #block1    { top: -150px; }

.thumb_content  { padding: 70px 15px 0 15px; color: #777; }
.thumb_content h1   { margin: 0 0 5px 0; color: #666; font-size: 14px; }


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="montage-wrap">

    <div class="montage-block">
        <span id="block1"></span>
        <div class="thumb_content">
            <h1>Sample Title</h1>
            <p>This is some sample title. yay for text.</p>
        </div>  
    </div> <!-- block end -->

    <!-- A sample Block -->
    <div class="montage-block">
        <span id="block1"></span>
        <div class="thumb_content">
            <h1>Sample Title</h1>
            <p>This is some sample title. yay for text.</p>
        </div>  
    </div> <!-- block end -->

</div> <!-- montage wrap -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please   http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3):

i changed the css `position: top`   to `margin:top`

Its worked for me

```
    #block1 { 
      width: 200px; 
      height: 200px; 
      position: absolute;  
     transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
    }
   .montage-block:hover #block1    { 
       margin-top: -100px; 
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X2y2H/)

Answer (score 1):

probably this is the one you wanted

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4AyZg/1/)**

```
 #block1 {
  background: url("pixelforlife_thumb.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
  transition-property: top;
  width: 200px;
    }
```

and on hover

```
 #block1:hover {
  top: -150px ;
}
```

don't use same id on same page. an ID is **unique** per page.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 span with the same id :

```
<span id="block1"></span>
```

Change id="block1" to class="block1" and don't forget to change it in your css too.